# Такой(,) как я. Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, как

Я видела уже не одну статью на такую тему, но все равно вопрос не дает мне покоя... Нужна ли здесь запятая? И зависит ли это от смысла?
“Такой(,) как я" подразумевается заголовком книги (пишу не я). Речь идет, насколько я знаю, о детях-аутистах.

Comment: Если о названии только речь, то оно может и не учитывать необходимые (в случае текста) знаки. Можно опустить зпт, а можно поставить вместо неё тире.

Comment: Первый раз вижу участника StackOverflow (StackExchange), у которого при 11 баллах репутации есть золотая медаль.

Answer (score 3):

Нужна. Обычное сравнение.

И [**правило**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722) очень простое:

обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».

*Такие, как ты, рождались во все эпохи кровавой истории наших планет.*

Эпизод с "переносом" запятой:

> В некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед
>   словом «такой»:
>
> 1) если слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным:
>   *Погода **дождливая, такая как осенью**. Обстановка в этом доме была **мрачная, такая как в старинных замках*** (ср.: *Погода такая, как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была такая, как в старинных замках);*
>
> 2) если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед
>   рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не
>   требуется): *Туристы посетили старинные города, такие как Суздаль,
>   Владимир, Ростов Великий.*

***Такой, как я.***